# Prove orthonormality and write $x$ as a linear combination, with

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

**Consider the following vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$**

$$
u_1=\left(\begin{array}{l}
{1 / 9} \\
{4 / 9} \\
{8 / 9}
\end{array}\right), \quad u_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}
{8 / 9} \\
{-4 / 9} \\
{1 / 9}
\end{array}\right), \quad u_3=\left(\begin{array}{c}
{4 / 9} \\
{7 / 9} \\
{-4 / 9}
\end{array}\right)
$$

**(a) Prove that the family $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ is orthonormal with respect to standard inner product on $\mathbb R^3$.**

*My answer*

For all the three vectors I got $<-,-> = 1$. The norm is $1$.

I have also proved that they are orthogonal.

**(b) Given an arbitary vector $x$
$$
x=\left(\begin{array}{l}
{x_{1}} \\
{x_{2}} \\
{x_{3}}
\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{3},
$$
determine $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb R^3$ such that
$$
x = u_1c_1+u_2c_2+u_3c_3
$$**

*My answer*

I actually do not have one. 
In the solution the first one $c_1$ is given as $c_1 = <u_1,x>$, and so on. I do not understand the thinking behind this.

Comment: I might be able to help with the second question. you showed in part a that u1, u2, and u3 are orthonormal and in R3. Thus, they form an orthonormal basis. part b then asks you to write an arbitrary vector (in R3) as a linear combination of the vectors u1, u2, and u3. You leverage here the normality and the orthogonality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are an orthonormal set, we can write any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ as linear comibation of those 3  as you have shown:

$$x=c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3$$

We can take the **Inner Product** of the right and left hand sides with respect to $u_1$, which should be equal:

$$\left(x,u_1\right)= \left(c_1 u_1,u_1\right) + \left(c_2 u_2,u_1\right) + \left(c_3 u_3,u_1\right)$$
Apply **Linearity Property** of inner product:
  $$\left(x,u_1\right)= c_1 \left( u_1,u_1\right) + c_2 \left( u_2,u_1\right) + c_3 \left( u_3,u_1\right)$$

Now recall that $\left( u_1,u_1\right)=1$, $\left( u_1,u_2\right)=0$ and $\left( u_1,u_3\right)=0$ because of the orthonormality of $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$, so:

$$\left(x,u_1\right)= c_1 $$

Repeat the same process with $u_2$ and $u_3$ to find $c_2$ and $c_3$.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose we already know that $x=c_1u_1+c_2u_2+c_3u_3$ for some numbers $c_1,c_2,c_3\in\Bbb R$, and apply inner product with $u_1$ on both sides.